# HTML5 canvas input string splitting

Tags: string, html, split

I am working currently in HTML5 canvas and i want to take user input(string) at runtime and store it in an array.And further i want to modify the properties of each letter from the input with different CSS styles. Hope to get answers soon.

Comment: Use JavaScript. By the way, why do you want to use Canvas to accept input? Use textboxes

Comment: Can u guide me further regarding details?